# highlighting xps file

Tags: wpf

I have the following code! I wonder if anybody knows how to highlight the text of an xps file in wpf?

thanks

```
        using System.Windows.Xps.Packaging;

  private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    //Absolute Path works (below)
        //var xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(@"C:\Users\..\Visual Studio 2008\Projects \MyProject\MyProject\Docs\MyDocument.xps", FileAccess.Read); 
    //Resource Path doesn't work (below)
    var xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(@"\MyProject;component/Docs/Mydocument.xps",    FileAccess.Read);
        DocumentViewer.Document = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
    }
```